# Pygame error 'pow expected 2 arguments, got 1'

Tags: pygame

They pygame game i made has run into an error i cannot figure out how to fix. I am new to pygame. I am using pycharm and python version 3.

The error is stopping me from doing anything and it won't even let me run it

Here is the error

```
TypeError: pow expected 2 arguments, got 1
```

Here is the code:

```
import math
import random

import pygame

pygame.init()
# Screen (Pixels by Pixels (X and Y (X = right and left Y = up and down)))
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
running = True
# Title and Icon
pygame.display.set_caption("Space Invaders")
icon = pygame.image.load('Icon.png')
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)
# Player Icon/Image
playerimg = pygame.image.load('Player.png')
playerX = 370
playerY = 480
playerX_change = 0


def player(x, y):
    # Blit means Draw
    screen.blit(playerimg, (x, y))


def enemy(x, y):
    # Blit means Draw
    screen.blit(enemyimg, (x, y))


def fire_bullet(x, y):
    global bullet_state
    bullet_state = "fire"
    screen.blit(bulletimg, (x + 16, y + 10))


def isCollision(enemyX, enemyY, bulletX, bulletY):
    distance = math.sqrt(math.pow(enemyX - bulletX, 2) + math.pow(math.pow(enemyY - bulletY,2)))
    if distance < 27:
        return True
    else:
        return False


background = pygame.image.load('247.jpg')

enemyimg = pygame.image.load('space-invaders.png')
enemyX = random.randint(0, 800)
enemyY = random.randint(50, 150)
enemyX_change = 4
enemyY_change = 40

bulletimg = pygame.image.load('bullet.png')
bulletX = 0
bulletY = 450
bulletX_change = 480
bulletY_change = 10
bullet_state = "ready"

score = 0
# Game loop (Put most of code for game in this loop)
while running:
    screen.fill((255, 0, 0))
    # BAckground
    screen.blit(background, (0, 0))
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        # if keystroke is pressed check whether is right or left
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                playerX_change = -5
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                playerX_change = 5
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                if bullet_state == "ready":
                    bulletX = playerX
                    fire_bullet(playerX, bulletY)



        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                playerX_change = 0

    # RGB (screen.fill) = red green blue
    # 5 = 5 + - 0.1 -> 5 = 5 - 0.1
    # making so nothing can go out of bounds
    enemyX += enemyX_change
    if enemyX <= 0:
        enemyX_change = 4
        enemyY += enemyY_change
    elif enemyX >= 736:
        enemyX_change = -4
        enemyY += enemyY_change
    playerX += playerX_change
    if playerX <= 0:
        playerX = 0
    elif playerX >= 736:
        playerX = 736

    # Bullet movement
    if bulletY <= 0:
        bulletY = 480
        bullet_state = "ready"

    if bullet_state == "fire":
        fire_bullet(bulletX, bulletY)
        bulletY -= bulletY_change

    # Collison
    collision = isCollision(enemyX,enemyY,bulletX,bulletY)
    if collision:
        bulletY = 480
        bullet_state = "ready"
        score +=1

    player(playerX, playerY)
    enemy(enemyX, enemyY)
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: A lot of the time it's quicker to use `( x * x )` rather than `math.pow( x, 2 )`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are trying to do this:

`c = sqrt(pow(a,2) + pow(b,2))`

But your code has one pow() too many. Happens to me too, when I make I make game sounds in my head, while coding (pew pew pew)

Try to remove one pow()

from
`math.pow(math.pow(enemyY - bulletY,2))`
to
`math.pow(enemyY - bulletY,2)`